# calling function in if statement inside map in react

Tags: reactjs, render

I am trying to map through an array which is being rendered by the control of an if-else statement but I want to call a function in that if-else statement but it is not working. Why?

```
import PropTypes from "prop-types";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import { NavLink } from "react-router-dom";
import { getQuiz, sendResponse } from "../../actions/quizzes";
import Navbar from "../layout/navbar";

class QuizDetail extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      currentStep: 0,
      selectedOption: null,
      questionId: null
    };
  }

  static propTypes = {
    user: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
    quiz: PropTypes.object,
    getQuiz: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
    sendResponse: PropTypes.func.isRequired
  };
  onSubmit = e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log("boulevard");
  };
  _setQuestion = questionId => {
    console.log("me");
    this.setState({ questionId });
  };
  handleOptionChange = changeEvent => {
    this.setState({
      selectedOption: parseInt(changeEvent.target.id, 10)
    });
  };
  _next = answerId => {
    let quiztaker = this.props.quiz.quiztakers_set[0].id;
    let answer = this.state.selectedOption;
    this.props.sendResponse(quiztaker, 1, 1);
    let currentStep = this.state.currentStep;
    let arrayLength = this.props.quiz.questions_count;
    currentStep =
      currentStep >= arrayLength - 1 ? arrayLength - 1 : currentStep + 1;
    this.setState({
      currentStep,
      selectedOption: null
    });
  };

  _prev = () => {
    let currentStep = this.state.currentStep;
    currentStep = currentStep <= 0 ? 0 : currentStep - 1;
    this.setState({
      currentStep
    });
  };

  componentWillMount() {
    this.props.getQuiz(this.props.match.params.slug);
  }
  render() {
    if (!this.props.quiz) {
      return <h1>LOADING...</h1>;
    }
    let icon_next =
      this.state.currentStep === this.props.quiz.questions_count - 1
        ? "fas fa-check"
        : "fas fa-angle-right";
    let icon_prev =
      this.state.currentStep === 0 ? "d-none" : "dir_control left";
    return (
      <Fragment>
        <Navbar />
        <div className="row question">
          <div className="card col-lg-8 col-md-8 mx-auto">
            {this.props.quiz.question_set.map((question, index) => {
              let { currentStep } = this.state;

              let style = {};
              if (currentStep === index) {
                () => this._setQuestion(question.id);
                style = {
                  display: "inline-block"
                };
              } else {
                style = {
                  display: "none"
                };
              }

              return (
                <div
                  className="card-body"
                  style={style}
                  key={question.id}
                  id={index}
                >
                  <form onSubmit={this.onSubmit}>
                    <h5 className="card-title">{question.label}</h5>
                    {question.answer_set.map(answer => {
                      return (
                        <div className="answers" key={answer.id}>
                          <input
                            type="radio"
                            name={answer.question}
                            id={answer.id}
                            value={answer.text}
                            checked={this.state.selectedOption === answer.id}
                            onChange={this.handleOptionChange}
                          />

                          <label htmlFor={answer.id}>{answer.text}</label>
                          <button
                            type="submit"
                            onClick={this._prev}
                            className={icon_prev}
                          >
                            <span className="fas fa-angle-left"></span>
                          </button>
                          <button
                            type="submit"
                            onClick={this._next}
                            className="dir_control right"
                          >
                            <span className={icon_next}></span>
                          </button>
                        </div>
                      );
                    })}
                  </form>
                </div>
              );
            })}
          </div>
        </div>
      </Fragment>
    );
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  user: state.auth.user,
  quiz: state.quizzes.quiz.quiz
});

export default connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  { getQuiz, sendResponse }
)(QuizDetail);
```

Whenever I try it without any parameters it works fine but when I add parameters it doesnt work at all.

Using the documentation on the react website led to no avail. I have tried everything to make this work. I have also tried stack overflow for a long time until I decided to ask the question myself.

P/S: I'm using class based component instead of functional component

Comment: You need to be a bit more specific than "it doesn't work" - do you get an error? what function are you trying to call? What do you expect to happen that isn't?

Comment: I dont it just doesnt get called!

Comment: so again, what function?

Comment: In the if statement the function that says this.DOSOMETHING. I expect it to call the function I define outside the render

Comment: well there is no `DOSOMETHING` function in your example, can you show the _true_ example that demonstrates the problem? I see no reason why any component function you have can't be accessed from inside your map call, particularly when you are using arrow functions.

Comment: There is a do something in my example, slightly above the form if you scroll down. Its inside the if statement. I increased the spacing so you can locate it.

Comment: I can see where you are attempting to call it....my point is, it's not _declared_ anywhere in the example - where do you declare `DOSOMETHING`?

Comment: My bad. That is meant to be setQuestion let me change that

Comment: ok now we're getting somewhere. So you have a console log in that function, do you at least hit that?

Comment: The console.log does not work. I believe it has to do with the setState method

Comment: you _definitely_ have no errors? Because you are trying to log an undeclared var `me` which would result in an error. Also, you don't need to bind `setQuestion` in the constructor, this is only required if you are going to pass it to a component.

Comment: That me was meant to be a string which I corrected. I removed the bind and it just does nothing when I call it like this ```() => this._setQuestion(question.id);``` but when I call it like ```this._setQuestion(question.id);``` It gives me the infinite loop because of setState

Comment: I updated the code BTW

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The recursion occurs because you *always* call `setState` in the `map` and don't tell the component to ignore re-renders if `questionId` is the same

```
shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps, nextState) {
  return this.state.questionId !== nextState.questionId;
}
```

Alternatively, you could add this protection in the `map` callback

```
let { currentStep, questionId } = this.state;

if (currentStep === index && questionId !== question.id) {
  this._setQuestion(question.id);
  ...
}
```

---

In fact, having said that this won't work regardless as you can't call `setState` during a `render`. This all becomes a lot easier if you move it to `componentDidMount` / `componentDidUpdate`

```
setQuestion() {
  const questionId = this.props.quiz.question_sets[this.state.currentStep];
  this.setState({ questionId });
}

componentDidMount() {
  setQuestion();
}
componentDidUpdate() {
  setQuestion();
}
```

Comment: @NSJCorps the second example is probably more suited to you as presumable you have various properties / states that you would want to trigger a re-render, it was just an example to show you how you can block additional renders

Comment: Where do I put the map callback

Comment: @NSJCorps huh? The code in the example would replace your existing `if` in the map callback func - I've omitted the other code for brevity.

Comment: how do I add a callback

Comment: Now it works but I am getting this error ```react-dom.development.js:506 Warning: Cannot update during an existing state transition (such as within `render`). Render methods should be a pure function of props and state.```

Comment: @NSJCorps d'oh, been too distracted with getting past the other minor issues to even notice that fatal design flaw! You can't call `setState` during a render, your best option at the minute would be to move the logic of calling `setQuestion` into `componentDidMount` / `componentDidUpdate` - these are triggered _after_ render has finished.

Comment: But then how will I get the question id passed in

Comment: Now I get this ```Uncaught TypeError: 0 is not a function```

Comment: ```Uncaught TypeError: 0 is not a function
    at Array.findIndex (<anonymous>)
 ```

Comment: @NSJCorps my bad, can just index straight in (see update)